# i'm confused on how the axiom of choice is used in the what is said in this textbook(i've attached the paragraph below)

Tags: set-theory

[image]

I've read the axiom of choice states that for a non-empty collection of sets X there exists a function f such that for every a in X, f(a) is contained in a, but I'm confused how this would apply to what's said in the text.

Comment: "Let $N$ be a subset of [0,1) that contains precisely one member of each equivalence class." uses the choice axiom. This implies a choice function from the set of equivalence classes to the declared subset.

Comment: This $f$ such that $f(a)\in a$ is a choosing function, it chooses our representative.

Comment: Thanks John Douma, that makes sense